# Brackets Live Preview-blank

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

I'm new to coding in general, and I'm just beginning to code my first website, but when I run this code in Brackets Live Preview, the page shows up blank. Not sure if I'm missing something, or if I have an error in the code. Thanks for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Finger Slipped</title>
    </head>

    <body bgolor="#000" text="#FFF">
        <h1>My Finger Slipped</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your pages isn't blank just that you make your body text the color white so you think its blank. Try highlighting the page you will see that there is text there. Typically you would wanna make a separate CSS page for you HTML and link it this way you can change your whole website by just adding div and id's.

**HTML**

```
        <title>My Finger Slipped</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My Finger Slipped</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #E5DAD3;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
}
```